# input textarea select conflict with mousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im stuck in a strange problem, I have elements with say class `.element` , and some of them are divs containing text, and when they get double clicked `ContentEditable`attribute becomes true so the user can edit the text and a class named `disabled` is added to the element being edited. The reason for it is that `.element` has a mousedown event attached to it as well, and I don't want the event being fired when the element is being edited because the user might want to select the text or re-position the caret. To do so I've added something like this to my mousedown event :

```
if(element.hasClass("disabled")) return false;
```

which doesnt work, but if I get rid my mousedown event, and use "click" event instead, it works perfectly. what should I do ?

edit: here is an example " http://jsfiddle.net/wqKke/ ... if you notice when you double click each element they become editable, but you're not able to select or reposition the caret in the element, so it's really hard to edit that element, but if you change the mouseover to click, the problem is solved !

Comment: A demo on http://JSFiddle.net or http://TinkerBin.com where the problem is being reproduced would make it much easier to help

Comment: sure @AmaanCheval I'll get on with it

Comment: @AmaanCheval example added mate

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is it that you want to do? You want to disallow selecting text or moving the caret with the mouse when the text is being edited?

Comment: @AmaanCheval no no, I want exactly opposite, I want the user to be able to select text/move the caret, because right now the user can't do that

Comment: I don't see why you have the `return false` on the `mousedown` event then. When do you want selecting text to be disabled?

Comment: @AmaanCheval got rid of false, and changed it to return; and fixed it. thanks ... if u want make it an answer so I can accept it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `return false;` in the `mousedown` event, which is what prevents the user from selecting text or moving the caret. I don't see a reason to have the `return false;` as all you want to do is prevent the code *after* from executing, which you can do by `return`ing anything.

So even this would suffice:

```
if(element.hasClass("disabled")) return;
```